# Calculate percentage for range of values in a dataframe column python

Tags: python, dataframe, percentage

I got a dataset named df_blue where i got two columns ("colour", and "length") and 7291 rows with different values.
see image as a sample of this dataset
(https://ibb.co/vYjDD8Q)

I need to know what is the percentage of total length in range : >15.625 and <17.755 (tolerences are inclusive)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify this:
"what is the percentage of total length"

total length means the length of the column or the sum of the column?

Comment: "percentage of the total length" means the length of the colum, sorry for the misunderstanding with the "sum of the column", I will be clearer for my next request. I'm a noob :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will give what you want:

```
df_blue[(df_blue['Length'] > 15.625) & (df_blue['Length'] < 17.755)]['Length'].sum() / df_blue['Length'].sum()
```

Comment: Why did you use sum? Since the percentage is wanted, the aggregation function must be `count` otherwise you ponderate with the length.

Comment: Yeah maybe you are right, I asked for some clarification from TS, as length is the name of the column too, so total length could mean sum

Comment: According to your comment, I find my solution, so much thanks for you comments and your supports !!! :-)

Comment: Happy to help @MercierRomain
Can you please accept the answer so that it will be removed from "unanswered" queue?
Cheers